# How does $o_K/\mathscr{p}$ arise from $Z/pZ$.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

once again, I have a question which is always treated as trivial, however, I don't understand how to spell it out:

The situation is the following: We have an algebraic number field $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and the corresponding integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ over $K$, denoted by $o_K$.

If we have a prime ideal $\mathscr{p} \neq 0$ in $o_K$, this corresponds to a prime $p\mathbb{Z}$. Now it is often claimed that $o_K/\mathscr{p}$ arrises from $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ as a finite field extension.

I know that nonzero primes in $o_K$ are maximal ideals and thus $o_K/\mathscr{p}$ is a field, however, I do not see why this should be a finite field extension and what algebraic elements are adjoined to get this.

Comment: $o_K$ is finitely generated free $\mathbb Z$ module. So show that $o_K/P$ is finitely generated $\mathbb Z /p \mathbb Z$ module.

Comment: Oh nice! If $o_K$ is generated by say $a_1,\ldots a_n$, then $o_K/P$ is generated by $a_1 + P, \ldots, a_n + P$. So this explains why it is a finite field extension :) Is there also a direct way to get what algebraic elements are needed to be adjoined to $Z/pZ$ to get to $o_K/P$ by looking at the elements adjoined to get to $o_K$ from $Z$?